# Cannot connect mongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

I am successfully running mongoDB v3.2.10 in terminal on macOS 10.11.6 and MAMP server running php 7.0.8.

When I try to reach mongo via php code like:

```
<?php
  // connect to mongodb
  $m = new MongoClient(); 
?>
```

at url: http://localhost:8888/Mongo/login.php

I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

When I reach mongo on the native port 
at url: http://localhost:27017/Mongo/login.php

I get:

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native
>   driver port.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: port is important, i assume that you run your apache on port 8888 and mongo run on port 27017, so adress `http://localhost:27017/Mongo/login.php` do not point at your php file at all, and mongo use own protocol `mongodb://` instead of `http://`

Comment: follow this tutorial link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm it help you

Comment: @vighaneshmandavkar This tutorial has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: @Kazz You are right. What I wanted to point out is that I am certain that mongo is running but, the connection is not working.

Comment: try specify server like: `new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');`

Comment: Tried that, no luck! @Kazz

Comment: then try by changing the port

Comment: My actual problem was that the OpenSSL wasn't correctly linked to MAMP. Homebrew did not let me linke it thus I had to do it manually. Now it works. I followed this tutorial http://railsrescue.com/blog/2016-08-24-brew-openssl-a-barrier-to-installing-ruby-2-3-on-os-x/ So my question was poorly formatted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the built-in PHP Mongo DB clients. There is a new MongoDB driver that replace that. You will have to install it.

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

The newer MongoDB extension replaces the built-in PHP Mongo DB client. You'll also want to use the composer PHPLIB MongoDB client from here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

```
use MongoDB\Client;

try {
    $mongoDbClient = new Client('mongodb://localhost:27017');
} catch (Exception $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage(); die(1);
}
```